# How to reset the X position of character in FreeType

Tags: opengl, glsl, freetype, freetype2

I want to break line with enter '\n' input in the string and render the text.

Currently if i try to break line after '\n' input the render output looks like this.[image]

I would like the second line to be aligned with the first line.

This is the code

```
// Iterate through all characters
    std::string::const_iterator c;
    for (c = text.begin(); c != text.end(); c++)
    {
        Character ch = Characters[*c];

        GLfloat xpos = x + ch.Bearing.x * scale;
        GLfloat ypos = y - (ch.Size.y - ch.Bearing.y) * scale;

         // i check the input here          
       //   if( *ch == '\n')
         //  Reset the Xpos value in the freetype.

        GLfloat w = ch.Size.x * scale;
        GLfloat h = ch.Size.y * scale;
        // Update VBO for each character
        GLfloat vertices[6][4] = {
            { xpos,     ypos + h,   0.0, 0.0 },            
            { xpos,     ypos,       0.0, 1.0 },
            { xpos + w, ypos,       1.0, 1.0 },

            { xpos,     ypos + h,   0.0, 0.0 },
            { xpos + w, ypos,       1.0, 1.0 },
            { xpos + w, ypos + h,   1.0, 0.0 }           
        };
        // Render glyph texture over quad
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ch.textureID);
        // Update content of VBO memory
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(vertices), vertices); 
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        // Render quad
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
        x += (ch.Advance >> 6) * scale; 
    }
```

Though i have been able to achieve this by incrementing a float variable by given value and subtracting the variable to the xpos.Which i feel is a workaround

Do we have any feature in freetype to reset the Xpos of the font to the start position.

Comment: *"Do we have any feature in freetype to reset the Xpos of the font to the start position."* - The font has no start position. The glyph position `x` is controlled by your code (freetype can't know how you do that). What is `x` at the beginning? Reset `x`, define a linefeed (`y = y + linefeed`) and `continue` the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
std::vector<std::string> stdvecInput;
boost::split(stdvecInput, stdstrTxt, boost::is_any_of("\n"), boost::token_compress_on);

for (auto &str : stdvecInput)
{
   for (cTmp = str.begin(); cTmp != str.end(); cTmp++) 
      {
           // Draw your font.
      }
 }
```